# Cannot reach reach jQuery (in parent document ) from IFRAME

Tags: php, jquery, dom

[image: My backup program]

I have written a backup program for SugarCRM. My program sets a iframe to src=BACKUP.PHP

My backup program sends updates to parent window with:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>parent.document.getElementById('file_size').value='".fileSize2human(filesize($_SESSION['archive_file_name']))."';parent.document.getElementById('file_count').value=".$_SESSION['archive_file_count'].";parent.document.getElementById('description').innerHTML += '".$log_entry."\\r\\n';parent.document.getElementById('description').scrollTop = parent.document.getElementById('description').scrollHeight;</script>";
echo str_repeat( ' ', 4096);
flush();
ob_flush();
```

I have added a JQUERY UI PROGRESS BAR and I need to know how I update the progress bar on the parent window.

I tried this:

```
$percent_complete = $_SESSION['archive_file_count'] / $_SESSION['archive_total_files'];

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>parent.document.jquery('#progressbar').animate_progressbar($percent_complete);
</script>";
```

......... and get this error in browser.

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object HTMLDocument] has no method 'jquery'

**HOW CAN I UPDATE THE PROGRESS BAR IN PARENT DOCUMENT FROM THE IFRAME?**

Comment: Jquery would be a property of the window, not the document.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the parent window with a function and I call the function like this:

```
          echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.parent.updateProgessBar(50);</script>";
```

and it worked

Here is the parent function:

```
            function updateProgessBar(percentComplete){
                $("#progressbar").animate_progressbar(percentComplete);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't because of security reasons.